# If condition to test if a command gives null or no output

Tags: bash, shell-script, aix

Im running a IP address collection from HMC on AIX for each LPAR

```
$ lssyscfg -m 780 -r lpar -F name:state:rmc_ipaddr:os_version --filter lpar_names=ABCD123
ABCD123:Not Activated::Unknown
$ lssyscfg -m 780 -r lpar -F name:state:rmc_ipaddr:os_version --filter lpar_names=ABCD456
ABCD456:Running:10.8.34.21:VIOS 2.2.5.20
```

Im using `cut` command with delimiter to get the IP details. The non IP values are not output data.

```
$ lssyscfg -m 780 -r lpar -F name:state:rmc_ipaddr:os_version --filter lpar_names=ABCD123 | cut -d : -f3
10.8.34.21
$ lssyscfg -m 780 -r lpar -F name:state:rmc_ipaddr:os_version --filter lpar_names=ABCD456 | cut -d : -f3
```

There are some servers with the IP address not available. How could I tell the if command to ignore the one with null or no output to assign a value unknown

Could you please tell me how to use test this condition for the no value data I can assign a variable  like `ipaddr=unknown`

Comment: Hi Kusalananda, DopeGhoti, William and ilkkachu, Thanks for giving the fix. ipaddr=$( lssyscfg -m 780 -r lpar -F name:state:rmc_ipaddr:os_version --filter lpar_names=ABCD123| cut -d : -f3 | grep . || echo unknown );echo $ipaddr
unknown
It gives me exact information what im looking for. You guys are really geeks

Comment: @kusalananda Need you help on another issue

Comment: I seldom look at how asks a question. If a question is interesting, then I will see it and consider it. Depending on the topic, someone interested in that topic will likely answer. You can not, however, request help from particular users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `bash`'s own built-in default parameter expansion:

```
ipaddr="$(lssyscfg -m 780 -r lpar -F name:state:rmc_ipaddr:os_version --filter lpar_names=ABCD123 | cut -d : -f3)"
echo "${ipaddr:-unknown}"
```

First, we use a subshell construct `$( command )` to capture the output of `command`, and assign that to a variable.  Since the command in question is including your `cut`, it will correctly be null as expected in the case where your command does not return an IP address.

We then use the construct `${var:-default}`, which will expand to the provided default value if `var` is unset or empty.

You can also, if you're going to be referring to that variable more than once, use a default assignation which will also *set* the value of that variable to the default if it is unset of empty:

```
$ echo "$foo"

$ echo "${foo:=bar}"
bar
$ echo "$foo"
bar
```

Or halt your script and throw an error if it's unset or empty:

```
$ echo "${bar:?bar is unset or empty}"
-bash: bar: bar is unset
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: Hi DopeGhoti, im using the delimiter : here so the 3rd value is null.

Comment: I copied the example command from your question which is purported to return the null output.

Comment: Hi Guys,I need another help also on the same command im caputing the state if its running or Not Activated in for loop. But it doesnt list the Not Activated systems on the for loop.# command - for status in `lssyscfg -r lpar -m $system -F name:state --filter lpar_names="$lpar" | cut -d: -f2`;
do
if [[ $status == Running ]]
then
state=Running
else
state=Not-Activated
fi

Answer (score 2):

```
for name in ABCD123 ABCD456; do
    ip_addr=$( lssyscfg -m 780 -r lpar -F name:state:rmc_ipaddr:os_version --filter lpar_names="$name" | cut -d : -f 3 )

    printf 'Got IP address "%s" for lpar name "%s"\n' "${ip_addr:-unknown}" "$name"
done
```

The parameter expansion `${ip_addr:-unknown}` will expand to the string `unknown` if `$ip_addr` is empty or if the variable is unset (it's always set to something here, but may be empty), otherwise it expands to the value of the variable `ip_addr`.

Comment: Hi Kusalananda, the 3rd value is null on one server and on other server it gives output

Comment: @satsensort Could you please explain that comment? Is it a question or a statement? I know that it gives nothing back for one server.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.  One technique is:

```
ipaddr=$( lssyscfg -m 780 -r lpar -F name:state:rmc_ipaddr:os_version \
    --filter lpar_names=ABCD123 | cut -d : -f3 | grep . || echo unknown )
```

Comment: Hi Guys,I need another help also on the same command im caputing the state if its running or Not Activated in for loop. But it doesnt list the Not Activated systems on the for loop.# command - for status in lssyscfg -r lpar -m $system -F name:state --filter lpar_names="$lpar" | cut -d: -f2; do if [[ $status == Running ]] then state=Running else state=Not-Activated fi